# Strict Inequality Using CDF

Tags: probability-distributions

Considering the definition of cumulative distribution function: 
$$F_{x}(x)=P[X\le x]=\int_{- \infty}^{x} f_{x}(x)dx$$ where $f_{x}$ is the probability density function of $x$, how can one obtain $P[X< x]$ ?  (Note the strict inequality)

Comment: Please use `f_X` and `F_X`, not `f_x` and `F_x`. Please do not use `x` both for the upper bound and for the argument of the integral.

Answer (score 3):

If the random variable $X$ has a PDF, then, for every $x$, $P(X=x)=0$ hence $P(X\lt x)=P(X\leqslant x)=F_X(x)$.

Comment: I'll keep in mind the corrections for the future. Thanks.